# How to make sbt console to return after initialCommands in console is executed?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm curious if there's a way to get the `scala>` prompt back after running initial commands in the console without having to hit "return".

For example in this project: https://github.com/underscoreio/creative-scala-template/blob/master/build.sbt the initialCommands will execute but not return so it looks like the program is hanging when really all you need to do is hit enter. I tried adding empty lines after the import block but that did nothing.

[image]

We can clarify this expectation in the documentation, but it would be lovely if we didn't have to.

This project is currently running Scala 2.12.4 and SBT 1.1.0

Desired output after running SBT console:

[image]

Comment: not really answering your question, but if you want to work from console, I would recommend ammonite REPL, it's much better than the default scala console. http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL

Comment: @lev And still doesn't work on Windows. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ At least not on my Windows 10, and not at all on my Windows 8.1.